# AOC-S3108L-H8iR SAS Fault LED

Tags: sas, supermicro, megaraid, raid-controller

The system was working fine when suddenly the drives were no longer available. Upon further inspection I found that the SAS Fault LED was lit on the RAID card and the megaraid software no longer show when booting up the system. The RAID card in use is [AOC-S3108L-H8iR](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/accessories/addon/AOC-S3108L-H8iR.php) but the [user manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/AOC-S3108L-H8iR.pdf) is of no real help. The only thing it says is

> Red: On | SAS Error(s) detected

I've already tried to move the card to a different PCIe slot and to change the cables but even with nothing connected the led keeps burning and the software stays unavailable.

Comment: Sounds like time to buy a new RAID card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the SAS cable, power down and up again, then try to enter the controller's setup during bootup. If that isn't possible the RAID controller's dead and needs replacement.

Comment: This was unfortunately the case. I've ordered a new card and replaced it and now it's working again.